# Access to processed versions of parameters inside OpenShift templates

Tags: templates, openshift

I need access to two version of an OpenShift parameter. The parameter is passed in e.g. with `oc new-app --template=my_template -p MY_PARAM=9.6`. In one version, it should appear verbatim (e.g. `9.6`), in the other it should have dots replaced by `x` (e.g. `9x6`). This is so that the "same" value can appear both as version number when installing packages (w/ dots) and as part of domain names (w/o dots).

Inside the OpenShift template, the first version is available as `${MY_PARAM}`, of course. Is there some construct for pre-processing a parameter when it is accessed (e.g. replacing dots by `x`s, or the inverse)? Or do I have to introduce two parameters (such as `MY_PARAM` and `MY_PARAM_X`) instead of one?

Comment: There is no way to do the sorts of on the fly edits you want to do with OpenShift templates. If you are going to need this time after time, you may want to look instead at using the automation broker (previously known as Ansible service broker) for handling the deployment.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thx. I'm interested in exploring the automation broker too, but will use two parameters for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have learned that such pre-processing is currently not possible on the level of OpenShift templates.

I will therefore use the workaround with two "similar" parameters `MY_PARAM` and `MY_PARAM_X`, as already hinted at in the question.